# How to remove overlapping uiimageview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I tried to change the image in the imageview but I can't seem to do that.
My code shown below creates a new subview for each image to display. However, the images just overlap and shows the overlapped images at the end which is not supposed to be.

.m:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [imageArr count]; i++) {

        NSArray *imageNameArr = [[imageArr objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

            check=line;
            NSString *msg = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Opening image: %@\n",[imageArr objectAtIndex:i]]];

            [textView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:msg waitUntilDone:NO];

               line=line+1;

            NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",jName,[imageArr objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *imageFile = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagePath];
            NSLog(@"------------------------------");
            NSLog(@"ImageFile: %@\n",imageFile);
            NSLog(@"Interger value: %i\n",i);

            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];
.....
.....
}
```

How to show the images individually, without overlapping?

Answer (score 2):

put this line out of for loop:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage]; 
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

and use it like:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

and use:

```
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImgNm]];
```

Inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You create the imageview out of loop and change the source(Image) for that imageview inside the loop.
You do this before loop starts,

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

and add the image like this inside the loop,

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFile]];
```